# How to translate with parameter in rails errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an error message that needs to be translated along with parameters. What is the best way to do it in rails?

```
dates = '12th June - 14th June'
errors.add(:base, :reserved_dates)
```

From `en.yml`

```
activemodel:
 errors:
  models:
   reserve_changes:
    reserved_dates: "Dates changes from %{dates}"
```

Expected output:

```
Dates changes from 12th June - 14th June
```

When running this way I only get `Dates changes from` without the passed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the `dates` as an option to the `errors.add`:

```rb
dates = '12th June - 14th June'
errors.add(:base, :reserved_dates, dates: dates)
```

Otherwise the translator has no access to the string you want to substitute.